# Merge values with the same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to values for a graph, and I want all values with the same date to merge.

This is the array I have now:

```
[ ['2012-10-09', 1], ['2012-10-09', 2], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-10', 4], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-11', 3] ]
```

And the result I want:

```
[ ['2012-10-09', 3], ['2012-10-10', 6], ['2012-10-11', 3] ]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
a.inject({}) { |h,(date, count)| h[date] ||= 0; h[date] += count; h }.to_a
```

Comment: +1 nice one. With `sum` as suggested by @dquimper I find the `group_by` alternative slightly more readable, but your answer does not depend on activesupport.

Comment: It's a classic "reduce" job ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using rails' [group_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), you can do this:

```
x = [ ['2012-10-09', 1], ['2012-10-09', 2], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-10', 4], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-11', 3] ]
x.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(0,&:+)] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mapreduce is a very powerful tool, but a little complicate to understand.
So it's the same thing using the sum method:

```
x = [ ['2012-10-09', 1], ['2012-10-09', 2], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-10', 4], ['2012-10-10', 1], ['2012-10-11', 3] ]
expected = [ ['2012-10-09', 3], ['2012-10-10', 6], ['2012-10-11', 3] ]

x.group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.sum(&:last)] }.should == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

its similar to Roman's answer but using the ternary operator

```
a.inject({}) { |h,(date,count)| h.has_key?(date) ? h[date] += count : h[date] = count; h }.to_a
```